# How to determine if a git merge was the wrong way

Tags: git, merge

So we have a branch structure where named branches merge up into the next version up like so...

```
version1 -> version2 => version3 -> etc
```

So any one particular version is a superset of its ancestor and a subset of its descendant.

Occasionally, it's happened that someone has accidentally merged "backwards" and we have found that its quite difficult to tell exactly where it's happened (i.e. what merge was backwards)

How can we easily deal with this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple way would be simply looking at the commit message of the merge. Usually the default commit message gives a good hint what happened. Unfortunately this does not work reliably as you are free to manually change the message and the local branch names do not have to be the same as the remote ones.

The best way I can think of is introducing a start tag on the first commit of each branch. In that case the start tag of one branch should never be reachable from any lower branch. You could write a push hook, refusing any merge violating that rule.

Comment: this is a really good idea, we were going to do something similar (but file based, as each branch has a version.txt file) but this would be easier and more reliable.